# how to disable log files for root login?

Tags: debian, logs

I don't want to disable all logs in Debian only ones that record when root logged in and for how long.

when I issue `last` command in terminal, I get my IP address, etc, I want to disable this.

when I go to `/var/log`, **btmp** file is empty, there is only some square sign, like unrecognized character, **wtmp** is the same. I deleted content of `auth.log`.

How can I disable this type of log?

Comment: What do you want to achieve and why? It sounds a little bit dodgy to me

Comment: Sometimes, when you're setting something up as root, and testing it as a regular user (e.g. Xorg), you may want to temporarily remove root logs in order to focus on the testing user more easily. Of course, that's the *gentle and naive* reason to do this.

Comment: Yeah this is almost definitely someone who rooted a server. Can this question be closed for that reason?

Comment: @JoelDavis - not sure which reason to use for this?

Comment: @slm Not sure either. Do your newfound moderator powers give you the ability to create new reasons or unilaterally lock the thread?

Comment: @JoelDavis - I cannot just create reasons. We can close the thread, that's about it.

Comment: @JoelDavis - You can always use the "other" option and type a custom close reason in yourself. However, you shouldn't just assume that someone is being nefarious when asking questions like this.

Comment: @JoelDavis - I asked and we cannot close this solely b/c it's viewed as potentially inappropriate.

Comment: This is a forum for Unix system administrators but the question only seems useful to someone who has compromised a server and wishes to cover their tracks from the actual administrators.

Comment: Added a custom reason, looks like it posted it as a comment above. I'm personally alright with giving people a lot of leeway in not assuming their reasons for asking a question but this question seems to serve no other purpose except to aid an attacker.

Answer (score 1):

#### Filtering the logs

I believe you can handle some of the logs using a filter within `rsyslog`. 
Specifically you'll need to add a filter to a configuration file under `/etc/rsyslog.d/`.

For messages like this in `/var/log/secure` (on Fedora 19 for example):

```
Jun 28 13:28:18 greeneggs login: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user saml by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jun 28 13:28:19 greeneggs login: LOGIN ON tty2 BY saml
```

You could use a filter like this to omit them:

> if $syslogfacility-text == 'local0' and $msg startswith 'login' and ($msg  contains 'root') then /dev/null

**NOTE:** Above is untested, but is just a example t show how you could approach this, roughly.

#### Filtering wtmp & btmp

These files are binary files and so you cannot simply edit them using standard tools such as `sed` and `awk`. If you truly want to edit them you'll have to do edit them from `cron` periodically. I couldn't find any method for filtering users from being added to either file as they logged in.

*excerpt from the [Utmp Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp)*

> #### utmp, wtmp and btmp
>
> - **utmp** maintains a full accounting of the current status of the system, system boot time (used by uptime), recording user logins at which terminals, logouts, system events etc.
> - **wtmp** acts as a historical utmp
> - **btmp** records failed login attempts
>
> The `utmp` file is not a text file, but rather a binary format which needs to be edited by specially crafted programs. The implementation and the fields present in the file differ depending of the system or the libc version, and are defined in the `utmp.h` header file.
>
> The `wtmp` and `btmp` format are exactly like `utmp` except that a null user name indicates a logout on the associated terminal. Furthermore, the terminal name ~ with user name shutdown or reboot indicates a system shutdown or reboot and the pair of terminal names / logs the old/new system time when date changes it.

To augment these files you could use the Perl module, [User::Utmp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/User-Utmp/Utmp.pm) to modify these files. Python has a similar module as well.

#### References

- [rsyslog.conf: Filter Conditions](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc-rsyslog_conf_filter.html)
- [syslog-ng: Filters](http://www.balabit.com/dl/html/syslog-ng-v3.0-guide-admin-en.html/ch03s06.html)